# Avoid error with cat command when src file doesn't exist

Tags: linux, file, unix, concatenation, cat

I am trying to copy content of file1 to file 2 using linux command

`cat file1 > file2`

file1 may or may not be available depending on different environments where the program is being run. What should be added to the command in case file1 is not available so that it doesn't return an error ? I have read that appending 2>/dev/null will not give error. While that's true, and I didn't get an error the command

`cat file1 2>/dev/null > file2`
made file2's previous content completely empty when file1 wasn't there. I don't want to lose the content of file2 in case file1 wasn't there and don't want an error to return.

Also in what other cases can the command fail and return an error ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Test for `file1` first.

```
[ -r file1 ] && cat ...
```

See `help test` for details.

Comment: Well, it's the perfect race condition.

Comment: @hek2mgl please explain how it causes a race condition and can it break my code ? What alternative should I use ?

Comment: The problem is that between the check and the actual creation of the file some other process might enter the cpu and create or delete the file. An alternative is the solution I've posted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47197501/171318

Answer (score 0):

elaborating on @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams :

```
if (test -a file1); then cat file1 > file2; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File1 is empty

File2 consists below content
praveen

Now I am trying to append the content of file1 to file2

Since file1 is empty to nullifying error using /dev/null so output will not show any error

cat file1 >>file 2>/dev/null

File2 content not got deleted

file2 content exsists
praveen 

If [ -f file1 ]
then
cat file  >> file2
else
cat file1 >>file 2>/dev/null
fi
```

Comment: This was in the case when file1 didn't exist, not empty.

Answer (score 0):

First, you wrote:

> I am trying to copy content of file1 to file 2 using linux command

To copy content of file1 to file2 use the `cp` command:

```
if ! cp file1 file2 2>/dev/null ; then
    echo "file1 does not exist or isn't readable"
fi
```

---

Just for completeness, with `cat`:

I would pipe stderr to /dev/null and check the return value:

```
if ! cat file1 2>/dev/null > file2 ; then
    rm file2
    echo "file1 does not exist or isn't readable"
fi
```